# accessing GUIText and recieveing NullReferenceException Error

Tags: c#, unity

I Have this line of code

```
public class HSLerp3 : MonoBehaviour {

   private GUIText textFade;
   private float startAlpha = 0f;
   private float damping = 0.5f;


   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {

      textFade = gameObject.GetComponents<GUIText>();

   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () {

       textFade.color = new Color (0, 0, 0, startAlpha);
       startAlpha -= damping * Time.time;

   }
}
```

It looks right, But I keep on recieving an error of:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

I'm trying to make a GUIText from scratch and by codes. been doin it for hours. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It cant find the object/component in your start void.

Make sure you have a GUIText component on the object you are referencing. 
Also its a good practice to be implicit by using

```
textFade = this.gameObject.GetComponent<GUIText>();
```

Oh and I just noticed you are using GetComponents<>; not GetComponent<>;
so if you need an array it should be

```
textFade = this.gameObject.GetComponents<GUIText>()[0]; //the array is which descending component to use.
```

Hope this helps, Cheers, 
Demetry.